# How to solve Notice: Trying to get property of non-object (Caused by table altering)

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I need to ask this question and I know this might get mark as duplicate since so many people already ask the similar questions but I have read through them and find no answers or similarities to the problem that I'm facing.

[Trying to get property of non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769027/notice-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-help)

Okay, right now, I have a table that will show the list of a user for admin to add, edit or delete the user. My problem right now is, the table can only display the users list and when I add the edit and delete part, the notice pops up.

This is my code before alteration of edit and delete;

```html
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'root'; // Username
$db_pass = ''; // Password
$db_name = 'register'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
 die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}

$sql = 'SELECT * 
  FROM users';
  
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
 die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
  
 <table class="data-table">
  <caption class="title">List of Users </caption>
  <thead>
   <tr>
   
    <th>USERNAME</th>
    <th>PASSWORD</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
  <?php
  $no  = 1;
  $total  = 0;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
   echo '<tr>
     <td>'.$row['username'].'</td>
     <td>'.$row['password'].'</td>
    </tr>';
 
  }?>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

[image: before alteration]

and here is my code after the alteration

```html
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'root'; // Username
$db_pass = ''; // Password
$db_name = 'register'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
 die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}

$sql = 'SELECT * 
  FROM users';
  
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
 die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
  
 <table class="data-table">
  <caption class="title">List of Users </caption>
  <thead>
   <tr>
   
    <th>USERNAME</th>
    <th>PASSWORD</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
  <?php
  $no  = 1;
  $total  = 0;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>" . $row->username . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->password . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='records.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Delete</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
 
  }?>
  </tbody>
 </table> 
  
</div>

</body>
```

[image: after alteration end up looking like this]

Where did I do wrong and how can I solve my problem?
Every suggestion and hints are greatly appreciated and please don't mark my question since I believe that my question is totally different from the others.

Comment: because `$row` is not a class or object. you want to use `$row['USERNAME']` because it was an array

Comment: I see...so that's where the problem lies. Thank you, I'll try that out and post the update.

Comment: Use `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query))` instead of `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))`